# The 'HasViewList' property cannot be set declaratively

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to run my crystal report through visual studio 2017.

Following tools are installed in machine .

1. SAP crystal report developer version for visual studio 2017
2. Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 redistributed.

When I am running project and trying to view report I am getting following error.

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The 'HasViewList' property cannot be set declaratively.

    Source Error: 


    Line 30:         <br />
    Line 31:     </div>
    Line 32:     <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="EspaceReportViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true"
    Line 33:         Visible="true" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="True" HasExportButton="True" HasPrintButton="True"
    Line 34:         HasViewList="True" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" Width="350px" HasCrystalLogo="False"

    Source File: /Report/Rpt/ReportViewer.aspx    Line: 32
```

Can any one please give me suggestion for solving this error?